# batch file with two variable dates

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to include a script in my batch file that copies file "X" from a directory, say, "[...]\2017\08 August\08.28" (previous weekday-1) to a directory: "2017\08 August\08.29" (previous weekday).

I currently do have two batch files which perform number of things for yesterday or 3 days ago (executing on Mondays), but I'd like to include that one line as well and preferably merge that into one file that automatically detects if the previous day is weekday, or not. What I do have now, simplified, is:

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"

if %MM%==08 (
set "mon=August"
)

copy "\2017\08 August\08.28\X" "\%YYYY%\%MM% %mon%\%MM%.%DD%"
```

How could I make that automatically adjustable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question wanders around a bit.  The key seems to be that you want to know if yesterday was a weekday.  This should help:

```
@echo off
set IYW_CURDAT=%DATE%
set IYW_CURDOW=%IYW_CURDAT:~0,3%
set IYW_YESWDY=TRUE
if /I "%IYW_CURDOW%" EQU "Sun" set IYW_YESWDY=FALSE
if /I "%IYW_CURDOW%" EQU "Mon" set IYW_YESWDY=FALSE
if [%IYW_YESWDY%] == [TRUE]  echo Yesterday was a weekday
if [%IYW_YESWDY%] == [FALSE] echo Yesterday was NOT a weekday
set IYW_CURDAT=
set IYW_CURDOW=
set IYW_YESWDY=
```

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever why didn't I do that myself. Thanks!